Symfony5.4 → 6.4 RememberMe is not recognized and logs me out when I set it as a cookie
Expected behavior
In order to upgrade from Symfony 5.4 to Symfony 6.4, we have removed the currently deprecated "TokenBasedRememberMeServices" and implemented the new RememberMe autologin feature.
I have written the following code in an acceptance test for RememberMe's auto-login feature.
Issue
MyPage::newInstance($this->getRouter(), $driver); process is correct to log in and transition to MyPage, but it logs out and transitions to a different page.
<?php

namespace Tests\Security;

use Facebook\WebDriver\Cookie;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Support\Events\EventFiringWebDriver;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Signature\SignatureHasher;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener;
use App\Entity\User;

class AutoLoginTest extends WebTestCase
    public function testAutoLogin(): void
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->registerUser();

        $handler = new SignatureRememberMeHandler(
            signatureHasher: static::getContainer()->get(SignatureHasher::class),
            userProvider: static::getContainer()->get(UserRepository::class),
            requestStack: $this->createConfiguredMock(
                RequestStack::class,
                ['getMainRequest' => $request = new Request()]
            ),
            options: [
                'name'     => 'REMEMBERME',
                'lifetime' => 604800,
            ],
        );
    }
    $handler->createRememberMeCookie($user);

    // create web driver for acceptance test
    $driver = $this->createWebDriver;

    // page object for no login user
    HomePage::newInstance($this->getRouter(), $driver);
    $cookie = Cookie::createFromArray(
        [
            'name'     => 'REMEMBERME',
            'value'    => $request->attributes->get(ResponseListener::COOKIE_ATTR_NAME)->getValue(),
            'path'     => '/',
            'domain'   => null,
            'expiry'   => time() + 604800,
            'secure'   => true,
            'httponly' => false,
        ]
    );
    $driver->manage()->addCookie($cookie);
    // -- ERROR --  page object for login user
    MyPage::newInstance($this->getRouter(), $driver);

remember_me:
    secret: secret
    lifetime: 604800
    path: /
    domain: ~
    name: REMEMBERME
    signature_properties: ['username', 'password']

<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Signature\SignatureHasher;

class SignatureHasherFactory
{
    public static function create(array $signatureProperties): SignatureHasher
    {
        $propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

        return new SignatureHasher($propertyAccessor, $signatureProperties, 'secret');
    }
}

Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Signature\SignatureHasher:
    factory: ['App\Security\SignatureHasherFactory', 'create']
    arguments:
        - ['getUsername', 'getPassword']
    public: true

Why is my RememberMe not working?
Implemented the above
